# Es posible mantener desplegada la lista de un combobox mientras se escribe en él? (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

estoy haciendo una app con tkinter y use el ComboBox para desplegar una lista de terceros a seleccionar. A medida se escribe en dicho Combobox, la lista de valores se va actualizando, eso ya lo tengo hecho, pero solo se ve los valores haciendo click en la flecha de desplegar, y toca nuevamente hacer click en el campo para seguir escribiendo, es posible ir escribiendo y dejar la lista desplegada? o un comando para que despliegue la lista al presionar una tecla y deje el cursor en el campo de escritura?

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Frame_cuentas(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.Nombre_tercero_def = StringVar()
        self.lista_terceros_defecto = self.master.Lista_nombres_terceros
        self.Lbl_Tercero_defecto = Label(self, text = "Tercero por defecto: ")
        self.Box_Tercero_defecto = ttk.Combobox(self, width=20, textvariable=self.Nombre_tercero_def, postcommand=self.actualizar_lista_terceros, values=self.lista_terceros_defecto)
        self.Lbl_Tercero_defecto.grid(row =2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady=10, sticky = "w")
        self.Box_Tercero_defecto.grid(row =2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady=10, sticky = "w")

    def actualizar_lista_terceros(self):
        valor_escrito = self.Nombre_tercero_def.get()
        if valor_escrito == "":
            self.lista_terceros_defecto = self.master.Lista_nombres_terceros
            self.Box_Tercero_defecto.config(values=self.lista_terceros_defecto)
        else:
            self.lista_terceros_defecto = []
            for nombre in self.master.Lista_nombres_terceros:
                nombre2 = nombre.lower()
                valor_escrito = valor_escrito.lower()
                if valor_escrito in nombre2:
                    self.lista_terceros_defecto.append(nombre)
            self.Box_Tercero_defecto.config(values=self.lista_terceros_defecto)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.Lista_nombres_terceros = ['CUANTIAS MENORES', 'UNA EMPRESA SAS', 'Humberto Puentes', 'Juancho Rario Fernandez Goza', 
    'EL SALAR LTDA', 'A DORMIR YA SAS', 'Jojojo Pepepe', 'Danilo Sanchez', 'UNITED FRUITS CO', 'Juan Camilo Perez', 'UNIGARRO LTDA', 'Andres Obando']
    root.pruebas = Frame_cuentas(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesante pregunta!

Lamentablemente, Tkinter no ofrece una forma directa de hacer lo que buscas. Es posible que a través de comandos de tcl (tkinter simplemente interactua con tcl) haya una forma, pero no encontré información de como poder modificar el combobox de tal forma que se logre lo que buscas.

Encontré una forma de enfocar el combobox, enviar un evento de teclado y luego enviar el evento de la flecha hacia abajo para volver a desplegar la lista, pero tiene dos problemas: la lista "parpadea" cuando escribe y el cursor del entry no es visible por que en realidad el propio entry no está enfocado.

Después de todo esto, llegué a la conclusión de que la mejor opción que se me ocurre es crear tu propia versión del combobox. A continuación, dejaré un pequeño ejemplo rapido. Si queres usarlo y mejorarlo, esa es tarea para el hogar c:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

# Creo una subclase de entry, esto es para que, por ejemplo
# el método config afecte al entry del combobox.
# Si subclasificamos el frame, para acceder al entry habría que hacer combobox.entry...
class Combobox(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        # creo un frame que contendrá los componentes del combobox
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(parent)

        # inicializo el entry con los argumentos de palabra clave pasados
        super().__init__(self.frame, **kwargs)

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.frame)

        # ubico el entry dentro del frame. Uso super para acceder al método "original",
        # ya que el otro llama a self.frame.grid
        super().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.listbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

    # esta "property" nos permite personalizar que pasa
    # cuando se accede o modifica un atributo, en este caso values
    @property
    def values(self):
        return self.listbox.get(0, "end")

    @values.setter
    def values(self, iterable):
        self.listbox.delete(0, "end")

        for item in iterable:
            self.listbox.insert("end", item)

    # redirigo grid a self.frame.grid
    def grid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame.grid(*args, **kwargs)

    # redirigo pack a self.frame.pack
    def pack(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame.pack(*args, **kwargs)

    # redirigo place a self.frame.place
    def place(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame.place(*args, **kwargs)

def change_values(*args):
    combo.values = [attr for attr in dir(combo) if(attr.startswith(var.get()))]

v = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var.trace("w", change_values)

combo = Combobox(textvariable=var)
combo.pack()

v.mainloop()
```

Esto de aquí basicamente es un frame que dentro contiene un entry y abajo un listbox. En el código mas abajo hago que el listbox obtenga todos los atributos del combobox que empiezan por lo escrito por el usuario. Como realmente el foco no cambia al listbox, se puede seguir escribiendo en el entry sin problema.